# ASP.NET MVC 4 AttributeRouting Multiple POST Actions in same controller

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Whenever I POST a request to my controller the Update action is always invoked. I am calling:

```
http://localhost/members/login/
```

However Update keeps getting the request. I have even tried switching the order of the actions in the controller to no avail.

```
[RoutePrefix("Members")]
public class MembersController : ApiController
{
    [POST("{member}")]
    public void Update(Member member)
    {
        //Do Some Stuff
    }

    [POST("Login/{member}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MemberLogin(Member member)
    {
       //Do Some Stuff
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because to the Api routing they are the same. [This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) greatly explain how routing and action selection is done in Web API. If you do not want to split them into two controllers then make `Update` as a `PUT` request. That should tell the routing engine that they are two different actions.

Comment: When I print my route table I see this: POST members/update/{member} 
controller: Members
action: Update

POST members/login/{member} 
controller: Members
action: Login, So I don't think they are seen as the same thing. They have different action names.

Comment: I have another PUT action in the controller; my "Add" action. So the result would be the same with that method and actions as well. I can get it to work if I register my routes individually, but I like using AttributeRouting.

Comment: What routing engine are you using?

Comment: <package id="AttributeRouting" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting.Core" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting.Core.Http" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting.Core.Web" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AttributeRouting.WebApi" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, by trial and error (many hours :/)

```
[RoutePrefix("Members")]
public class MembersController : ApiController
{
    [POST("Update")]
    public void Update(Member member)
    {
        //Do Some Stuff
    }

    [POST("Login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MemberLogin(Member member)
    {
       //Do Some Stuff
    }
}
```

Not sure why this works, but I'm sure it will come to me eventually.